# codignieter nested views

Tags: codeigniter, view, controller

I'm trying dynamically to initialize my controllers methods and gather the output data for my  nested views. I would like to avoid to check every time the instance of $data['something'] in the view and function of this call the appropriate view php file.

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function _remap($method, $params = array())
    {
        $this->view($method, $params);
    }
    public function view($method, $params)
    {
        $param = (implode(",", $params));
        $data = array();
        if (method_exists($this,$method) ){
            $param = !empty($param) ? $param : '';
            $data = call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), array($param));
            // and load the data array in the main view
            $this->load->view('admin/dashboard', $data);
        } else {
            $this->load->view('admin/404', $data);
        }
    }

    public function _one_of_mymethod(){
        $data['nested_view'] = 'view1';
        //calling models gather $data
        return $data;
    }

}
```

than in function of data array output the right nested view.

**Main View**

would be something like

```
<div class="sidebar"><?php $this->view('admin/sidebar'); ?></div>
<div id="content"><?php $this->view('/admin/'. $nested_view) ?></div>
```

but this seems not the right approach to be in case if I use ajax calls. What is the best way to add nested views dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery you can always use JQuery $.load method like this

```
$('.sidebar').load('<?php site_url('controllername/methodname')?>');
```

And here is the method name

```
function methodname(){
    $this->view();
   // do any stuff you want.
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback mainly I think my logic what I build is not the best one

Comment: @fefe i would recommend you to read Jamie Rumbelow's My_Controller. It does exactly what you want. His first book is available you can read and learn too many great techniques.